Can Martire and Bobrick's general warp metrics all produce CTCs?
It's well known that the Alcubierre metric allows for the creation of CTCs under the assumption that warp bubbles with arbitrary relative velocities can be created (Everett, Physical Review D, 1996).
However, there are many other examples of what might be called "warp metrics." Martire and Bobrick (2021, Classical and Quantum Gravity) cover four classes of spacetimes, of which the Alcubierre metric and certain other metrics are a subset.
Setting aside the dubious physicality and practicality of these metrics and the energy or mass needed to realize them, do all of them suffer from the Alcubierre metric's problem of being able to construct two bubbles that together produce a CTC? Or is this argument not necessarily general?

Some would argue that warp drives do not create CTCs at all. Could you detail the reasoning you cite as to why they do (or at least link the paper to make it easier to find)?

@controlgroup - Sure, if an answerer can persuasively find a flaw in Everett's paper, they can certainly do so. Everett claims to use the Alcubierre metric, "with no additional assumptions," to generate CTCs via two trips with different relative velocities.

I didn't specialize in relativity, so the argument in the paper looks facially plausible to me, but it might not be correct, and there are lots of papers that take the argument as correct, while I can't find any claiming to debunk it.

I have not been able to obtain the same results, but the effects of warp drives on causality/whether they could be used to form CTCs is still sort of an open question (since doing an empirical test is difficult to say the least). It doesn't merit a full answer but I would generally say that CTCs can form in spacetimes that allow FTL (i.e. inside a Kerr black hole), but there exist spacetimes that allow $v>c$ that don't create CTCs; I couldn't provide a proof, hence no answer, but that's what I know so far.

All the ones leading to superluminal motion (the interesting ones!) will do. No matter how they are built, from far away they roughly will look like pointlike tachyonic particles, then arguments such as the Tachyonic antitelephone will apply, leading to causality violations.

This answer could possibly benefit from a rigorous demonstration that this is the case. The idea looks plausible, but whether it is correct will presumably depend on what "far away" and "looks like" actually mean mathematically in the context of relativity. Is there some research that has established this, or could you provide your own proof here?

If you zoom far away and draw a space-time diagram in which the superluminal warp is a point, it will behave as a tachyonic point, by definition. The only way out of this is arguing that the warp is not a localised space-time phenomenon, but this is not what we usually mean by warp drive. Yet these problems pops up even with tubes (see krasnikov tubes https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9702049  and hypertubes https://arxiv.org/abs/2311.12069), since you can join tube like regions to make closed circuits.
